# Relocating server to new datacenter, can't ping gateway

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server that I just moved from one datacenter to another and I have 2 network devices configured as follows:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto em3
iface em3 inet static
  address 28.53.45.6
  netmask 255.255.255.240
  gateway 28.53.45.1
  dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# The internal network interface
auto em2
iface em2 inet static
  address 192.168.2.6
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I can ping all the local servers in the cabinet on the 192.168 network, I can also access them all from the public IP. From another server I can SSH into the server using it's public IP,  but it can't ping the gateway. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to access the server from the outside? Have you verified with the DC that they have finished the setup?

Comment: If ServerA is the new one and ServerB was already there, I can't access ServerA from outside, but I can by using SSH to ServerB and then SSH@ServerA from ServerB. I have had half a cabinet for 3 years, the DC isn't involved in the setup anymore, I physically installed it myself.